# Convergence of sequence of sups and sequence of infs of bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Let us define
>   $y_n := \text{sup}\{x_k : k \ge n\}$ and $z_n := \text{inf}\{x_k : k \ge n\}$. Deduce that $\{y_n\}$ and $\{z_n\}$ are convergent sequences.

Comment: What have to tried ? take a look : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 0):

Check out [limsup and liminf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior). One way of the defining them is precisely as the limit of your $y_n$ and $z_n$ sequences. An important property is that they both always exist (even in the case $x_n$ is unbounded as long as you allow limits to $\pm \infty$).

Try to prove that $y_n, z_n$ are monotone, bounded sequences. A standard result then gives that they are convergent.

Comment: how can i prove that yn,zn are monotone bounded sequences? and is it enough to deduce that {yn} and {zn} are convergent sequences?

Comment: Bounded is trivial by boundedness of $x_n$. Monotone follows directly from definitions of inf and sup. That bounded monotone sequences converge is a standard and easy result (hint: take sup of an increasing sequence and take inf of decreasing sequence). I can't help you more if you don't show an attempt at a proof. I have given more than enough to easily construct a proof.